# Javascript execution blocking SVG animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I'm facing following issue. HTML:

```
<div id='loading'>
    <svg> /* inline SVG with animateTransform tags */ </svg>
    <span>Loading, please wait...</span>
</div>
<button id='generateResult'></button>
<span id='result'></span>
```

JS:

```
$('#generateResult').click(function(){

    $('#loading').fadeIn(100, function(){

        // After showing the 'loading' container, run the calculate_result function
        let result = calculate_result();
        // When it's done, output the result into #result span
        $('#result').html(result);

    });
});
```

Note: This is not actual code, just a shortcut example.

The problem is that executing the `calculate_result` function takes about 10 seconds. During that time the `#loading` container should be visible, which contains an animated `svg` loading icon. But for some reason, the `calculate_result` function causes the SVG icon to stop animating.

Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: It would be nice to be able to see the svg animation. Please check if you don't have a "loading" id inside the svg element.

Comment: That's really not the issue. The #loading container is being faded in without any problems. The thing was that when it was animating (fading in), the animation was visibly running. After the fade finished (so when the `calculate_result()` started), the SVG animation stopped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded. If JS code is running, the browser cannot do *anything* else, and that includes re-drawing the screen. So, your animation appears to stop.

If you have a long-running JS code, you should put it in a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) so that it can run on a separate thread and "message" the main thread when it's done working. This will allow the browser to continue responding to user interaction and draw the "loading" animation.